# How do matrilineal marriages work in Crusader Kings 2?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I am having trouble understanding the matrilineal marriage dynamic in Crusader Kings 2.  A couple of times, I've had a female member of my dynasty marry someone matrilinearly who has then ascended to, say Baron or King.  The problem is, they have had children, and the children, who are then heirs, have been of the (more powerful) father's dynasty.

I was under the impression that all children born of a matrilineal marriage would be of my dynasty, hence why I married my daughters off to powerful husbands in the first place!  I must be missing something, so how does this mechanic work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, all children born of a matrilineal marriage will be of the mother's dynasty. Therefore a couple things come to mind that might cause what you are seeing.

1. you made a matrilineal betrothal but the AI offered a traditional marriage when the characters came of age and you accepted. AI likes to do this, its very sneaky. You can double check if the marriage is matrilineal based on the overlapping rings on the character screen. Even if the AI does try this you can just reject the offer and send a matrilineal offer and the AI will accept.
2. The lord had a bastard child and legitimized it, or had children via a previous marriage. Check if the mother is in fact the member of your dynasty.

Comment: Aha!  I'm almost certain the first option is what happened.  Thank you very much, I won't make that mistake again!

Comment: On the latest patches, the AI should no longer be pulling that kind of trickery - it'll send the originally agreed upon marriage. However, if the marriage is no longer agreeable to them, they won't cancel the betrothal, leaving that up to you (2.0.4, not sure about 2.1.X)